# Single Page Application with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

What I'm trying to do in my Single Page Application is that whenever a login button is clicked it fetches an html FORM from the nodejs server using XMLHttpRequest and then displays it in the display area. After filling the form and clicking the button it again fetches other HTML Forms from the server. Following is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

     const login = document.querySelector("#login");

      const displayArea = document.querySelector("#displayArea");

      login.onclick = () => {

         loginPage('GET', '/login');

      };


     const loginPage = (method, url) => {

         let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

         xml.open(method, url);

         xml.onload = () => {

             let loadPage = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);

             document.title = loadPage.title;

             displayArea.innerHTML = loadPage.form;

             const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

             submit.onclick = (e) => {

                 e.preventDefault();

                 loginAuth();

             };

         };

         xml.send();

     };

     const loginAuth = () => {

         const username = document.querySelector("#username");

         const password = document.querySelector("#password");

         let auth = {

             username: username.value,

             password: password.value

         };

         let url = "/login/" + JSON.stringify(auth);

         const xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

         xml.open('POST', url);

         xml.onload = () => {

             let loadPage = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);

             document.title = loadPage.title;

             displayArea.innerHTML = loadPage.form;

         };

         xml.send();

 };});
```

Since the Form data is not available / visible outside the calling function, the challenge is if I keep fetching the HTML Forms within the functions it will be a nested function call. How do I avoid that situation? Is there an easy way out?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what will become a nested function call, and why? It's unclear what you mean, or why, if nested functions did occur, why that would be an issue. Can you give a worked example, and explain your concern in more detail? It's not clear how any functions to deal with other forms would affect the code you've already shown, either.

Comment: First I called loginPage which fetched an HTML form. Then I called loginAuth which is again fetching an HTML Form. Once I submit that form again then I'll be calling another function.

Comment: "Once I submit that form again then I'll be calling another function". Ok. But that has nothing to do with nesting, as far as I can see (you still haven't provided a concrete example which would involve it). And if you want to submit the newly downloaded form, you have to run a function (assuming you wish to submit via AJAX, which in an SPA context you would). How else would you propose to handle it? It's still unclear what actual problem you are trying to solve here. Please explain why calling another function to submit a form would cause you a difficulty.

Comment: P.S. you might want to consider using a front-end framework which is designed for building SPAs (e.g. Angular, React, Vue etc, one of those). It will be easier to build something complex, without tying yourself up in a knot of dependencies (or worries about dependencies, whether real or imagined). These frameworks have tried-and-tested structures and features which make this kind of work easier, as well as documentation, support communities etc. Your current approach is a little naive, if I'm honest, and is unlikely to scale well.

Comment: Maybe I have to think over it from a different point of view.